Is mindfulness linked to prospective memory?
Recently, I came across a Scientific American article on prospective memory (PM). I couldn’t help but notice the similarities between PM and mindfulness as below:

Both have significant impact on our well-being. Failure to be mindful just like failure to remember or carry out a future intention have a direct impact on our happiness.

Both mindfulness and PM deals with the future. In the case of mindfulness, one needs to keep the Dharma in mind and apply it to whatever circumstances (involving thoughts, speech or actions) that may arises.

The quality of both are affected by alcohol consumption.


So, could mindfulness be a form of PM? I suppose one way is to measure PM quality in practitioners of mindfulness to see if there is a positive correlation. If there is a positive correlation, could this also be an objective measurement w.r.t the quality of a person’s mindfulness?

Mindfulness is PM. Right mindfulness, for example, reflects upon what is right speech before engaging in speech. Refer to MN 117 & SN 46.3.

Memory usually means remembering things that have already happened.
But prospective memory is the ability to remember to do something in
the future – such as stopping to get milk on the way home from work,
calling your mom on her birthday or remembering to take your casserole
out of the oven. Sometimes, errors lead to heartbreaking results –
such as forgetting to take your toddler out of the car on a hot day


PM - setting an intention and carrying it out - is describing those intentions that generate pleasure and happiness with regards to the six-sense media.  Mindfulness is the intention that generates pleasure and happiness free from reliance on the six-sense media, so no, they are not the same.
Here is a product of mindfulness from MN14:

...“ We now ask you, master Gotama: Who lives in greater pleasure:
King Seniya Bimbisāra of Magadha or master Gotama?’
“‘In that case, Nigaṇṭhas, I will question you in return. Answer as
you like. What do you think? Can King Seniya Bimbisāra of
Magadha—without moving his body, without uttering a word—dwell
sensitive to unalloyed pleasure for seven days & nights?’
“‘No, friend.”
“‘… for six days & nights.… for five days & nights… for a day & a
night?’
“‘No, friend.”
“‘Now, I—without moving my body, without uttering a word—can dwell
sensitive to unalloyed pleasure for a day and a night… for two days &
nights… for three… four… five… six… seven days & nights.6 So what do
you think? That being the case, who dwells in greater pleasure: King
Seniya Bimbisāra of Magadha or me?’
“‘That being the case, master Gotama dwells in greater pleasure than
King Seniya Bimbisāra of Magadha.’”


@fake i prefer it, especially with u, happy now?

But what reminds us of our intention to be mindful when we are forgetful, heedless or complacent? Could the process of remembering to be mindful be a PM process? Also, correct me if I am wrong but I thought the passage you quoted in MN14 refers to the bliss of jhana.

u r right, this answer is not correct, perhaps it is a diatribe

Earlier I was also thinking that sati is related to short term memory. So if we are mindful our short term memory is continuously blocked for mindfulness.
however through practice and through, further understanding. I realised that thats not true. Though it is initially true while we are learning. but when we say your mindfulness is established(sati upathāpetvā). its not short memory.
E.g when I get distracted, and stay distracted for 10 minutes. totally involved into discursive thinking. and almost lost the purpose. sati is gone. then what it is that brings me back after 10 minutes?  not only that, If I diligently keep practicing then this 10 minutes reduces year over year.
Similarly, in my early days I was able to stay with meditation object for only 30 seconds. Now I stay with meditation object for 2 minutes on average and 5 minutes pick.
So these two parameters 'staying-with-object' and 'staying-distracted' will decide my strength of mindfulness. and obviously it is coming from somewhere else instead of short term memory. probably it is coming from where sankharas resides. where my skill of cycling, driving, etc resides.

+1 for answer from direct experience!
